# Scrolling on mobile causing content to shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently working on this website redesign and I am having this issue when I scroll down the screen on mobile devices the content area width will shrink.

It only does this when I am using an actual mobile device, if I used Chrome's built in mobile device tester ti works as expected.

I have tried setting a min width for the div to 100%, but it didn't stop the issue.

Just as a note, this is my first time doing a full site build from scratch and am still relatively new to web development.

[image: Normal Look, Before Scroll]

[image: After Scroll]

I have added a working example of the site, except for the navbar JavaScript and the images for the page.

```js
var isMobile = {
  Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
  BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  },
  Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
  Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
  },
  any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Page Layout change events
  if (isMobile.any()) {
    $('#super-container').removeClass("super-container").addClass("super-container-mobile");
    $('#header-row').removeClass("column-row").addClass("column-row-mobile");
    $('#header').removeClass("header-container").addClass("header-container-mobile");
    $('#main-row').removeClass("row").addClass("row-mobile");
    $('#footer-row').removeClass("row").addClass("row-mobile");
    $('#main-content').removeClass("main-content-container").addClass("main-content-container-mobile");
    $('#RightBar').removeClass("right-bar").addClass("right-bar-mobile");
    $('#footer-row').removeClass("footer").addClass("footer-mobile");

  } else {
    var viewWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewWidth < 870) {
      $('#header').removeClass("header-container").addClass("header-container-smaller");
      $('#main-content').removeClass("main-content-container").addClass("main-content-container-smaller");
      $('#RightBar').removeClass("right-bar").addClass("right-bar-smaller");
      $('#footer-row').removeClass("footer").addClass("footer-smaller");
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.super-container-mobile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.column-row-mobile {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2E4986;
}

.header-container-mobile {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2E4986;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: .25em;
}

.row-mobile {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.main-content-container-mobile {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #000;
}

.right-bar-mobile {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 70%;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  color: #FFF;
}

.right-bar-mobile .rightbar-well {
  font-size: .75em;
}

.right-bar-mobile .right-bar-header {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.footer-mobile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2E4986;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .75em;
}

.footer-mobile p {
  padding: .5em;
}

.content-cell-mobile {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 95%;
}

.content-cell-mobile .main-content-body {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.main-content-header-mobile {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.right-bar-header-mobile {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: #FFF;
}

.rightbar-well {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #2E4986;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #2E4986;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #212121;
  margin-top: .75em;
  margin-bottom: .75em;
}

.rightbar-well a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.body-img {
  height: 8em;
  width: auto;
}

.body-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.company-header {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sub-header {
  margin-top: .1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.header-line {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: .05em;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-top: .2em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 31px 1px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Header-Master">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Community Action, Inc.</title>

  <style>
    .fixed-inv {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: auto;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .fixed-vis {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: auto;
    }
    
    .Links {
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    
    .Links-mobile {
      font-size: 1.75em;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body id="mainbody">
  <!-- Super Container that holds all of the row containers -->
  <div id="super-container" class="super-container-mobile">
    <!--Header Row container -->
    <div id="header-row" class="column-row-mobile">
      <div id="header" class="header-container-mobile">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img alt="CAI Logo" src="./Images/Basic-logo.png" class="header-img" id="logo">
        </div>
        <div id="header-text">
          <div>
            <span class="company-header">Community Action, Inc</span>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-top: .5em;">
            <span class="sub-header">Primarily Serving Clarion and Jefferson Counties, Pennsylvania</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header-line"></div>
      <div id="nav" class="stellarnav light mobile"><a href="#" class="menu-toggle full"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
          <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Annual Report</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\01-02 Annual Report.pdf">2014 - 2015</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\01-02 Annual Report.pdf">2013 - 2014</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\Annual Report 2012 - 2013.pdf">2012 - 2013</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\11-12 Annual Report.pdf">2011 - 2012</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\2010-2011 Annual Report.pdf">2010 - 2011</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\2009-2010 Annual Report.pdf">2009 - 2010</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\08-09-Annual-Report.pdf">2008 - 2009</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\07-08-Annual-Report.pdf">2007 - 2008</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\06-07-Annual-Report.pdf">2006 - 2007</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\05-06-Annual-Report.pdf">2005 - 2006</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\04-05 Annual Report.pdf">2004 - 2005</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\03-04 Annual Report.pdf">2003 - 2004</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\02-03 Annual Report.pdf">2002 - 2003</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Fiscal\01-02 Annual Report.pdf">2001 - 2002</a></li>
                </ul><a class="dd-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="uploads\Bylaws - Last Revised March 20, 2014.pdf">Bylaws</a></li>
              <li><a href="uploads\Charitable Organization Certificate.pdf">Charitable Organization Certificate</a></li>
              <li><a href="history.aspx">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="uploads\Project Guide - October 25 2013.pdf">Project Guide</a></li>
              <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Strategic Plan</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="uploads\Strategic Plan.pdf">Strategic Plan</a></li>
                  <li><a href="uploads\StrategicPlanSummary.pdf">Strategic Plan Summary</a></li>
                </ul><a class="dd-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="links.aspx">Resources</a></li>
              <li><a href="board.aspx">Board</a></li>
              <li><a href="Financial.aspx">Financials</a></li>
            </ul><a class="dd-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">News</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="Newsletters.aspx">Newsletters</a></li>
              <li><a href="NewNewsRelease.aspx">News Releases</a></li>
            </ul><a class="dd-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="project.aspx">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="locations.aspx">Locations</a></li>
          <li><a href="employment.aspx">Employment</a></li>
          <li><a href="emergencies.aspx">Emergencies</a></li>
          <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Staff Only</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/website_test/admin">Administration</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://mail.jccap.org/owa">Outlook Web App</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://staff.jccap.org">Staff Portal</a></li>
            </ul><a class="dd-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Main Row container -->
    <div id="main-row" class="row-mobile">
      <div id="main-content" class="main-content-container-mobile">

        <div id="MainContentpnl">


          <div class="content-cell-mobile">
            <div class="main-content-header-mobile">Job Announcements</div>
            <div class="Links-mobile"><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/job_posting.aspx?JID=1100">Accountant</a><br><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/job_posting.aspx?JID=1081">Community Services Assistant</a><br><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/job_posting.aspx?JID=1061">Information Technology Support Specialist</a><br>
              <a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/job_posting.aspx?JID=1057">Information Technology Manager</a><br></div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Free Home Weatherization</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. is accepting weatherization applications from Clarion, Indiana, and Jefferson County residents. Weatherization is a free government funded service intended to make your home more energy efficient and comfortable
                  by stopping ai...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1542">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names INDIANA County Senior Corps-RSVP June Volunteer of the Month</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(579 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1548_Image.jpeg" alt="Community Action, Inc. announced Lawrence Rager of Indiana was selected to be the Indiana County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for June." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Lawrence Rager of Indiana was selected to be the Indiana County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for June. Lawrence has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since October 2014 volunteering for
                  the Community ...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1548">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names INDIANA County Senior Corps-RSVP August Volunteer of the Month </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(582 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1553_Image.jpeg" alt="Eleanor Haney of Indiana was selected to be the Indiana County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for August." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Eleanor Haney of Indiana was selected to be the Indiana County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for August. Eleanor has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since April 2001 volunteering for Aging
                  Services, ...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1553">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names JEFFERSON County Senior Corps-RSVP August Volunteer of the Month </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(583 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1554_Image.jpeg" alt="Tom Brandon of Brookville was selected to be the Jefferson County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for August." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Tom Brandon of Brookville was selected to be the Jefferson County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for August. Tom has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since October 2013 volunteering for
                  Jefferson Count...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1554">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names CLARION County Senior Corps-RSVP August Volunteer of the Month </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(585 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1556_Image.jpeg" alt="Betty Siegel of Leeper was selected to be the Clarion County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for August." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Betty Siegel of Leeper was selected to be the Clarion County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for August. Betty has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since February 2010 volunteering for Clarion
                  Area Agen...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1556">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names JEFFERSON County Senior Corps-RSVP July Volunteer of the Month </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(577 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1546_Image.jpeg" alt="Louise Deyarmin of Punxsutawney was selected to be the Jefferson County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for July." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Louise Deyarmin of Punxsutawney was selected to be the Jefferson County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for July. Louise has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since August 2014 volunteering
                  for the Punxs...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1546">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names INDIANA County Senior Corps-RSVP July Volunteer of the Month </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(580 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1551_Image.jpeg" alt="Carole Bell of Indiana was selected to be the Indiana County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for July." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Carole Bell of Indiana was selected to be the Indiana County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for July. Carole has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since January 2015 volunteering for Aging
                  Services, Inc...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1551">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Community Action, Inc. Names CLARION County Senior Corps-RSVP July Volunteer of the Month </span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-img">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPicture(581 );"><img src="./Images/New_Release/1552_Image.jpeg" alt="Carol Brooks of New Bethlehem was selected to be the Clarion County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for July." class="body-img"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc. announced Carol Brooks of New Bethlehem was selected to be the Clarion County Senior Corps-RSVP Volunteer of the Month for July. Carol has been a member of the Senior Corps-RSVP since February 2010 volunteering for
                  the New Beth...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1552">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">Be the Source of Change!  Volunteer Today!</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>Community Action, Inc.'s Career Development Project needs classroom volunteers and tutors to assist instructors and mentor students who want to improve their reading and math skills. For more information, please contact the Career Development
                  Projec...
                </p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1466">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-cell-mobile"><span class="main-content-header-mobile">I Got My GED, You Can Too</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="left-align">
              <div class="main-content-body">
                <p>I achieved my GED through Community Action, Inc.’s Career Development Project, and my life has really turned around for the better. I made a quick decision to quit school when I was in the eleventh grade. I tried Cyber School, but it didn’t
                  work ou...</p><a href="http://development2.jccap.org/NEWSITE_TEST/news_release.aspx?NRID=1519">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div id="RightBar" class="right-bar-mobile">
        <div class="rightbar-well">
          <span class="right-bar-header">Mission Statement</span><br><br>Community Action, Inc. will be a community catalyst to provide and coordinate activities which promote family self-sufficiency and advance community prosperity.
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="rightbar-well">
          <span class="right-bar-header">Vision Statement</span><br><br>Community Action, Inc. will be recognized as a premier organization dedicated to solving social and economic problems of the community.
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="rightbar-well">
          <span class="right-bar-header">Contact Information</span><br><br>
          <div><a title="Community Action, Inc." href="http://www.jccap.org/Map_Main.aspx">Community Action, Inc.</a></div>
          <div>105 Grace Way</div>
          <div>Punxsutawney, PA 15767-1209</div>
          <div>Phone: (814) 938-3302</div>
          <div>Toll Free: 1-800-648-3381</div>
          <div><a href="contact@jccap.org">contact@jccap.org</a></div>
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="padding rightbar-well text-center">
          <span class="rightbar-headerText">Newsletters</span><br><br><a href="newsletters/Crossroads Connection Fall 2013 - October 30, 2013.pdf">Crossroads Connection - Fall 2013</a><br><a href="newsletters/Crossroads Connection Fall 2012 - September 26, 2012.pdf">Crossroads - September 2012</a><br>
          <a href="newsletters/Senior Corps RSVP - July 2012.pdf">Senior Corps RSVP - July 2012</a><br><a href="newsletters/Crossroads-Connection-Fall-2011-10-26-2011.pdf">Crossroads - October 2011</a><br><a href="newsletters/Senior-Corps-RSVP-Summer-2011-Newsletter.pdf">Senior Corps RSVP - August 2011</a><br>
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="padding rightbar-well text-center">
          <span class="rightbar-headerText">Newsletters</span><br><br><a href="important_notices/Whistleblower Policy - Effective March 20 2014.pdf">Whistleblower Policy</a><br><a href="important_notices/Home Improvement Contractor's Certificate.pdf">Home Improvement Contractor's Certificate</a><br>
          <a href="important_notices/Community Action Needs Volunteers.pdf">Community Action Needs Volunteers</a><br><a href="important_notices/Non-Discrimination Delivery of Services Policy - Notice to CAI Consumers - Revised October 30, 2013.pdf">Non-Discrimination Delivery of Services Policy</a><br>
          <a href="important_notices/Equal Employment Opportunity Affirmative Action Policy - Revised October 30, 2013.pdf">Equal Employment Opportunity &amp; Affirmative Action Policy Statement</a><br>
        </div><br><br></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer Row container -->
    <div id="footer-row" class="row-mobile footer-mobile">
      <p class="footer-padding">
        All persons are provided services without regard to race, color, religious creed, age, sex, ancestry, union membership, sexual orientation, gender identity, national or ethnic origin, disability and without regard to whether the person is a victim of
        a violent crime (including domestic violence). Equal Opportunity Employer.
        <br>
        <br> This site was financed in part by a grant from the federal Department of Health and Human Services under the Administration of the Commonwealth of Pennsylvania, Department of Community and Economic Development.
        <br>
        <br> The official registration and financial information of Community Action, Inc. may be obtained from the Pennsylvania Department of State by calling toll free, within Pennsylvania, 1-800-732-0999. Registration does not imply endorsement.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide working demo on codepen so we can actually identify the issue. This is not helping.

Comment: I don't get it, you're showing us a css for lot of classes that are not used in your html. I suppose you showed a wrong html. Or is there some way that you append 'mobile' to those classes?

Comment: Probably you will need to provide the complete css that you have used otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell you with just what you showed is that when you are working with multiple devices, for responsive design, you should not forget the viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Place it inside your `<head>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not maintaining the margins of your body and also not maintaining the text justification.

```
.super-container-mobile {
 width: 90%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto 10px;
 text-align: justify;}
```